# Mongo DB .find_one(query) doesn't find results

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to check if a user exists in my database based on the contact information (`name`, `surname`, `email`) that I have retrieved from data. I know that this information exists in my database but for some reason I am unable to spot the error.. please help!

This is my function:

```python
def check_user_present(self, data):
        # Extract contact information from the provided data
        contact_info = {
            "contact information": {
                "full name": {
                    "name": data["contact information"]["full name"]["name"],
                    "surname": data["contact information"]["full name"]["surname"]
                    },
                "email": data["contact information"]["email"]
                }}
        # Check if the contact information is already present
        print(contact_info)
        document = self.personal_info_collection.find_one()
        if document:
            print("Sample document from 'personal_info' collection:")
            print(document)

        existing_user = self.personal_info_collection.find_one(contact_info)
        print(existing_user)
        # If the user is already present, return a flag message
        if existing_user:
            reference_id = existing_user.get("profile ID")
            self.update_user(reference_id, data)
            return "The user is already present"
        # If the user is not present, call the save_to_mongodb function
        self.save_to_mongodb(data)
```

the output for `print(contact_info)` is : `{'contact information': {'full name': {'name': 'R****l', 'surname': 'P****o'}, 'email': 'r************@hotmail.com'}}`

and the output for `print(document)`: is `{'_id': ObjectId('6501d03f0209edbee1fd88f8'), 'profile ID': '6501d03e0209edbee1fd88f7', 'contact information': {'full name': {'name': 'R****l', 'surname': 'P****o'}, 'email': 'r************@hotmail.com', 'phone': ''}, 'sources': {'LinkedIn': 'www.linkedin.com/in/r****', 'website': '', 'GitHub': ''}}`

`exising_user` is always `None`

this is all part of a class that initiates the connection to the database

I have also tried `document = self.personal_info_collection.find_one(query)` but it does not return anything.

There seems to be no hidden characters or whitespaces, the data types seem to match (all strings) and it seems the case of the field names and values in my query matches exactly with the case in the database.

i'm not even sure what else i can try to debug

Comment: The ordering of the keys may be important.  You might want to try with `pymongo`'s [`son`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/son.html) or possibly even with Python's [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: ... also see, [_"Key order in subdocuments – why does my query work in the shell but not PyMongo?"_](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#key-order-in-subdocuments-why-does-my-query-work-in-the-shell-but-not-pymongo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your "contact information" document also has a field called "phone". [According to the MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.2/core/read-operations/#subdocuments), because it is a subdocument, you need to provide all fields.

> When the field holds an embedded document (i.e. subdocument), you can either specify the entire subdocument as the value of a field, or “reach into” the subdocument using dot notation, to specify values for individual fields in the subdocument

Applying this to your query should be:

```
       contact_info = {
        "contact information": {
            "full name": {
                "name": data["contact information"]["full name"]["name"],
                "surname": data["contact information"]["full name"]["surname"]
                },
            "email": data["contact information"]["email"]
            },
            "phone": ""
        }
```

Comment: Might be useful to mention the dotted notation for querying fields in an embedded document